# I can't change the text in the TextView (kotlin)

Tags: textview, fragment

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pagina_agenda,container,false)
        val textView: TextView=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView5)
        textView.text = "eee"
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pagina_agenda, container, false)
    }
```